# Average Value of a Surface

Tags: calculus

For a project I am working on I'm attempting to get the average height of a surface. That is, for a function $z = f(r, \theta)$ I would like to obtain the average z value within a specified radius and angle.

For a single variable, the average value would be $1/(b-a)\int^b_af(x)dx$; however, I'm not certain how to apply this to a surface.

I would assume that the answer is to take an integral and then divide by the area instead of $a-b$. For example, if the function were $f(r, \theta) = r^2$ the mean value of the function between $r=[0, r_0], \theta=[0, 2\pi]$ would be $1/(\pi r_0^2) \int^{2\pi}_0\int^{r_0}_0r^2r\ dr\ d\theta$.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: That is correct.  In general, for a region $R$ of the polar coordinate plane defined by some relation $R(r,\theta)$,  the average value of some function $f(r,\theta)$ over $R$ is given by $$\frac{1}{|R|} \iint_R f(r,\theta) r \, dr \, d\theta.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The average value of a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ in a set $A$ is:

$$\bar{f}=\frac{\int_A f} {\int_A 1}$$

For $n=1$, the denominator is just the length of $A$; for $n=2$ is the area; for $n=3$, the volume, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Just to make certain I understand correctly, the area I need to use in the denominator is the area of the region, not the area of the surface, correct? That is, it will be $\pi r^2_0$ regardless of what function I am averaging.

Comment: Yes. You want the average of the function $f$ over the circle.

Comment: It is the same as if you were asked to compute the average height of a function over an interval.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, 
$$
\overline{f}=:\frac{1}{\mu(E)}\int_{E}fd\mu
$$

is the average of $f$ over the set $E$, when $\mu$ is positive measure.

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, for example,

$$\overline{f}=\frac{1}{\alpha(n)r^n}\int_{B(x,r)}f dy$$

is the average of $f$ over the ball $B(x,r)\subset \mathbb{R}^n,$ when $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of unit ball $B(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.